# How to set permission set license to list of users?

Tags: administration, permission-sets

I have a list of 6000 users (from different profiles nearly 15 profiles). I need to set the Permission set license to all users. 
Actually, we can assign a license to individually as below 
[image]

[image]

But i need to activate this license for total 6000 users at a time?

Can anyone help me to achieve this?
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 3):

The object you are looking for is **PermissionSetAssignment**. Its a junction object between PermissionSet and The user.

So what you have to do is Use dataloader and load PermissionSetAssignment Records and the users will get the desired permission set.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_permissionsetassignment.htm

Dataloader for Pemission Set : https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hD7OAAU

Alternatively, you can use Apex for this.

Answer (score 2):

Easy solution. You can use 3rd party apps to bulk assign permission sets to your users. Some good examples:

1. [Permcomparator](https://perm-comparator.herokuapp.com/)
2. [Permissioner](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000008XYMlEAO)

You can do this in any environment (Production, Sandbox). Choose this option if assigning permission sets is done on regular basis in you org.

More advanced solution. If the app above do not meet your requirements, consider programmatic approach and write your own tool/script. You can customize it to handle as many assignments as needed in one go. Take a look at this [article](http://www.salesforcehacker.com/2015/01/api-first-for-administrators.html) to get an idea of how you can do this.

Comment: These apps can be used in production.

Comment: I have never used app to do such things. Can any other user know if i use this app in production? If yes I should not let them know that i have used. What should i do for that?

Comment: If you are an admin, install the app for admins only. Other users (except) admins will not have access to it. If you are concerned about your users should not now that their permission sets were assigned by an app, then worry not. The app actually would run on your behalf and all Modified By fields would contain your name. It's true though that an admin can figure out whether these assignments were made by an app by looking into the EventLog object.